# Media Player in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, media-player

I want to develop a media player in python from scratch for ubuntu . Please suggest me some good libraries to work with . It'll also be helpful to know where to start with . Thanks in advance

Comment: You can take a look at this tutorial for building a simple media player - http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/multimedia/creating-a-simple-media-player/

Comment: What do you mean by "from scratch"? When I think of "from scratch", I don't think of finding libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want [gst-python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html).

Comment: thanks Ignacio . gst-python seems to be very interesting . thanks for the help

Comment: hey what about PyMedia ? which one is better ?

Comment: Two things come to mind. First, using PyMedia *may* restrict your ability to distribute your application since it uses codecs that require licenses. GStreamer uses the codecs that the user has elected to install and provides a common interface to all of them. Second, PyMedia is only for decoding and encoding the files, whereas GStreamer also provides things such as video windows and subtitle handling.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help Ignacio . I'll start with gst-python

Answer (score 0):

Here are good examples to look at :

1. Google's python audio interface project :

http://code.google.com/p/py-audio/

2 . Python Codec registry and base class :

http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html

3 . Here's python wrapper for FFmpeg :

http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/